# How to make a POST to Eloqua by rest api?

Tags: c#, asp.net, rest, eloqua

I am working with eloqua 10.

I need to create Email in eloqua by using their rest api from an aspx web page.But am get `404 Bad Request`.

Given below is the code sample for the POST request that I tried.

```
string authenticateStr = eloquainstance + @"\" + username + ':' + password;

byte[] bytesToEncode = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(authenticateStr);

string encodedText = Convert.ToBase64String(bytesToEncode);

string requrl = "/assets/email";

string requestBody = "<subject>Test subject</subject>" +
                        "<senderName>Ajai Test</senderName>" +
                        "<senderEmail>amani@suyati.com</senderEmail>" +
                        "<emailGroupId>9</emailGroupId>" +
                        "<htmlContent>This is a test email templete created     trough rest api.This is for testing purpose only</htmlContent>"+
                        "<type>Email</type>" +
                        "<name>Email By api</name>";


HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(baseurl + requrl);
request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + encodedText);
request.Accept = "application/xml";//"application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
request.Method = "POST";
request.ContentType = "application/xml";
request.ContentLength = requestBody.Length;

//write body to text
byte[] body = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(requestBody);
Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
dataStream.Write(body, 0, requestBody.Length);
dataStream.Close();

HttpWebResponse webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
```

Please correct me if anything wrong in my code.

Can anybody tried a post using eloqua rest api, if so can you share a sample code to make a POST request to eloqua from c#.Any help be appreciable.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure whether you've got this working yet as some time has passed since you asked this, but you can find a whole set of samples for using eloqua's topliners site:

http://topliners.eloqua.com/community/code_it/blog/2012/10/08/eloqua-rest-api--open-source-c-samples

Looking at your code I think you may need to escape the html body

I would also consider writing a class to represent the email object and then use [restsharp](http://restsharp.org) to simplify the process of serialising the request and handling the response.

Also experiment with test requests using fiddler.